# Search nearby in iOS Maps

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, google-maps-sdk-ios, apple-maps

I am trying to build a simple application using MapKit that will automatically search for a specific place when the app launches and drop pin(s) on the map at the locations(s). I am seeing all sorts of ways to load locations (lat/lon, etc), but nothing that lets me search for a specific business name, restaurant name, etc.

I am expecting to work with Apple Maps. However, if Google Maps would be a better solve than so be it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share code samples of what you've tried, so we can help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

iOS >= 6.1 provides [MKLocalSearch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearch/Reference/Reference.html), [MKLocalSearchRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKLocalSearchRequest_class/Reference/Reference.html) to search for natural language points of interest. Sample

```
MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = regionToSearchIn;
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurants"; // or business name
MKLocalSearch *localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    // do something with the results / error
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

i know its late but hope this helps!

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[self.ibSearchBar setDelegate:self];

self.ibMapView.delegate=self;

// Zoom the map to current location.
[self.ibMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[self.ibMapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.ibMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow];



CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate=self;

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
[self.ibMapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2))];

MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
request.region = self.ibMapView.region;
request.naturalLanguageQuery = @"restaurant";

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
localSearch = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[localSearch startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKLocalSearchResponse *response, NSError *error){

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    results = response;
    if (response.mapItems.count == 0)
        NSLog(@"No Matches");
    else
        for (MKMapItem *item in response.mapItems)
        {
            NSLog(@"name = %@", item.name);
            NSLog(@"Phone = %@", item.phoneNumber);

            [_matchingItems addObject:item];
            MKPointAnnotation *annotation =
            [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
            annotation.coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate;
            annotation.title = item.name;
            [self.ibMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
}];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make the following steps to display nearest places.

Using google API find the Nearest Places [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

The google API provide LAt and Long and address Informations.

Then Store the LAt and Long Values to Array then USing this lat and long values you can display Annotations in Apple map (iOS 6+) and Google Map (iOS 5).

Comment: Beginning with iOS6 This is not allowed according to the Google Places TOS. It says you must use a Google Map if you display Google Places results.

Comment: The original question asked about MapKit, not a third party service. Sanjit's answer below is the correct answer.