# Find the distance between my location and a point in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a method to get my location:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {


CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

NSLog(@"%@", currentLocation);}


//new method to find the distance
        -(void) zoomToNearestSpot: (NSArray *) spot location: (CLLocation *)myLocation
    {
        myLocation = currentLocation;

        spot = chSpot;

        for (int i=0; i< spot.count; i++)
        {
        ChargingSpots *mySpot = [spot objectAtIndex:i];

        CLLocation *thePoint = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[mySpot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[mySpot.LocationLong doubleValue]];

        CLLocationDistance dist = [myLocation distanceFromLocation:thePoint];

            NSLog(@"%f", dist);


       you get here **distance** in meter so in assumption  **20 miles = 32187 meter**
```

put condition such like

```
if(distance <= 32187)
{
  // under 20 miles   you can add the zoom level
}
else
{
  // out of 20 miles
}



        }
    }
```

First, I need to show all of the spots on the map by zooming out according to their number then find the nearest spots and zoom in the camera on them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have more the two coordinate

> 1) current (user Location)
>   2) another coordinate ..

Here [distanceFromLocation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocation/distanceFromLocation:) method is use for get distance between two location.

```
CLLocationDistance distance = [currentLOcation distanceFromLocation:anotherLocation];
```

for example where you need add the following lines

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
              fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {

  CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

   for (int i=0; i<chSpot.count; i++)
 {

     ChargingSpots *spot = [chSpot objectAtIndex:i];
     NSString *locLat = spot.LocationLat;
     NSString *locLong = spot.LocationLong;

     CLLocation *LocationAtual = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: locLat longitude: locLong];

     CLLocationDistance distanceBetween = [currentLocation
        distanceFromLocation: LocationAtual];

     NSString *tripString = [[NSString alloc] 
       initWithFormat:@"%f", 
       distanceBetween];

     NSLog(@"DIST: %f", tripString); 
   }

 }
```

Comment: How to get "currentLocation" value from my method ?? I need to add this code in the "ViewdidLoad" not in the method

Comment: declare **CLLocation *currentLocation** in globally

Comment: ok this is great but my spot is declared in the ViewDidLoad and all its attributes are used there so how to get the lat and long from it ??

Comment: sorry one last thing, this code depends on some previous lines in the ViewDidLoad also, I have updated my code so u can see it

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- as your wish you can delete the code from view didload and add in delegate method , else part get the location and create the custom method , else chSpot --> create the memory for this array and add value for this , you can implement this concept in multiple ways

Comment: can you tell me how to get the nearest spot ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- there are two ways 1. you can get the all spot from your server(backend side), 2. use google api for find near locations

Comment: how to use the second way ?

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930121/search-nearby-in-ios-maps

Comment: i need to get the nearest spot from the spots i got from my server

Comment: I agree u get multiple spots from server, u need follow this step , initially fetch current location then compare the spot location based on meters , or miles , etc, then show the spot in map , thats all

Comment: yes this is exactly the point that I am stuck in , how to get my current location , fetching it from the method and deal with it in my viewDidLoad

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- that is the answer I submit for you bro  CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;--> this is the line u get user location

Comment: i agree with you, this is inside the idUpdateToLocation method right ??
I mean after that how should I pass this value to the viewDidLoad in order to deal with it ?

Comment: your viewdidload method is fine ,but you missed one thing chSpot--> NSArray change this into NSMutablearray and create the memory for this just enough , after the code will execute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89505/discussion-between-abdelrahman-manna-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: are you available to ask you ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- sorry for delay , now only I seen the message , what I do for you

Comment: I have made a method to find the distance between my current location and the points, now I want to determine the nearest points and zoom the camera on them, the method is written above in the code (zoomToNearest)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- this is fine ,choice --1 in here you can get the array of distance , after that distance sort your array based on ascending or descending and zoom on comes underwith your order , choice no -2 : you can get distance in this distance set your limit like range (maximum 2 kms ) , whatever comes under with in 2 kms shows the details in zoom else leave it , got it

Comment: but how can I can show them all at the beginning then zoom in at the nearest ? i mean if there is a code that can help me

Comment: great but how can i save the distance i get from a method into a variable and use it ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna -- in my assumption no need to save , you can directly access it , if you need any assistance (karthik.saral@gmail.com (Facebook, twitter, Skype, gmail,stackoverflow)), my whatsapp no - +91-9790811202,

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

1.) `CLLocation *loc=[[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:spot.LocationLat longitude:spot.LocationLong];`

2.) `CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters=[currentLocation distanceFromLocation:loc];`

This will help.ThankYou

Comment: How to get "currentLocation" value from my method ?? I need to add this code in the "ViewdidLoad" not in the method

Comment: well make it class datamember , currentLocation outside this function - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {} .